# Change FragmentActivity working with asynctask

Tags: java, android

I'm want to make User register system.. I'm using Facebook SDK and I can send user information my Database from comes to Facebook and successfully registered. But I want to show different fragment activity after this.

If user access my application on Facebook, I'm sending users data Async Class (different class not inner class)

In the summary when my server return the Json data I want to close MainFragmentActivity class and open StartFragmentActivity

I couldn't do it in onPostExecute function with Intent. How can I do it ?

Thanks for help and I'm sorry my poor English

```
private void makeRequest(final Session session){
    Log.d("deneme","makeRequest ÇALIŞIYOR");
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if(session == Session.getActiveSession()){

                if(user != null){
                    new MyAsyncTask(getActivity(), "ssoLR", user.getName(),
                            user.getId(), user.getProperty("email")
                                    .toString());
                }
            }
        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

My AsyncTask Class like this,

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

public MyAsyncTask(FragmentActivity a, String tag, String username, String password, String email){

    this.mMain = a;
    this.tag = tag;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;

    execute(tag, username, password, email);

}

@Override
protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
    if(tag.equals("ssoLR")){
        postData(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]);
    }
    return null;
}

public void postData(String tag, String username, String password, String email) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://<my website");

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", tag));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
        stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String buffer = null;
        while((buffer = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null){
            stringbuilder.append(buffer);
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){

}

HttpResponse response;
StringBuilder stringbuilder;
private String tag, username, password, email;
}
```

Comment: are you calling MyAsyncTask from your MainFragmentActivity or is it from some other activity?

Comment: I'm calling MyAsyncTask from Fragment, and I call Fragment to FragmentActivity